# Low Memory Killer - error message within Cordova/Android app

Tags: android, cordova, adb, hybrid-mobile-app, low-memory

I have a Cordova 7.0.1 application that occassionally crashes when using the camera function - I have got the output of the adb logcat to see the errors returned from adb.

```
08-10 17:14:36.321   493   493 F DEBUG   : Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_07
08-10 17:14:36.321   493   493 E DEBUG   : AM write failed: Broken pipe
08-10 17:14:36.321   493   493 E         : ro.product_ship = true
08-10 17:14:36.321   493   493 E         : ro.debug_level = 0x4f4c
08-10 17:14:36.321   493   493 E         : sys.mobilecare.preload = false
08-10 17:14:36.331  3739  3739 E audit   : type=1701 msg=audit(1502381676.331:336): auid=4294967295 uid=10202 gid=10202 ses=4294967295 subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 pid=10658 comm="Chrome_InProcRe" reason="memory violation" sig=4
08-10 17:14:36.431   438   438 E lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/10614/oom_score_adj; errno=22
```

I am running this on a Samsumg Galaxy Note 4 (approx 3 years old) running Android 6.0.1 - can anyone suggest the best way to prevent this 'low memory killer' killing this application?

- cordova info

  ```
  Node version: v6.10.3
  Cordova version: 7.0.1
  ```
- cordova plugins

  ```
  cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera"
  cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
  cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 2.3.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
  cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.0 "Whitelist"
  ```

Note - this is using the Crosswalk WebView Engine rather than the default WebView (due to issues with another Angular directive)

The phone is updated to the Android security patch level from 1st July 2017 - the app itself is being run as the only application running within the foreground.

-- update --
I managed to crash the app again here is the logcat if it helps

```
08-11 09:37:52.270 11740 11776 F libc    : Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 1, fault addr 0x9d151ea8 in tid 11776 (Chrome_InProcRe)
08-11 09:37:52.340   484   484 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
08-11 09:37:52.340   484   484 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'samsung/trltexx/trlte:6.0.1/MMB29M/N910FXXS1DQG5:user/release-keys'
08-11 09:37:52.340   484   484 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
08-11 09:37:52.340   484   484 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
08-11 09:37:52.340   484   484 F DEBUG   : pid: 11740, tid: 11776, name: Chrome_InProcRe  >>> com.abc.abc.123 <<<
08-11 09:37:52.340   484   484 F DEBUG   : signal 4 (SIGILL), code 1 (ILL_ILLOPC), fault addr 0x9d151ea8
08-11 09:37:52.410   484   484 F DEBUG   :     r0 98efb93c  r1 03c92000  r2 0d7bc000  r3 08000000
08-11 09:37:52.410   484   484 F DEBUG   :     r4 9f3e32b8  r5 03c8d000  r6 00000000  r7 00000000
08-11 09:37:52.410   484   484 F DEBUG   :     r8 03c92000  r9 94947834  sl 03c8c400  fp 9f3e32b8
08-11 09:37:52.410   484   484 F DEBUG   :     ip 9d151e99  sp 98efb938  lr 9d151ea9  pc 9d151ea8  cpsr 280d0030
08-11 09:37:52.420   484   484 F DEBUG   :
08-11 09:37:52.420   484   484 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
08-11 09:37:52.420   484   484 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 0023fea8  /data/app/com.abc.abc.123-1/lib/arm/libxwalkcore.so
08-11 09:37:52.420   484   484 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 0023fea5  /data/app/com.abc.abc.123-1/lib/arm/libxwalkcore.so
08-11 09:37:53.670   484   484 F DEBUG   :
08-11 09:37:53.670   484   484 F DEBUG   : Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_09
08-11 09:37:53.670   484   484 E DEBUG   : AM write failed: Broken pipe
08-11 09:37:53.670   484   484 E         : ro.product_ship = true
08-11 09:37:53.670   484   484 E         : ro.debug_level = 0x4f4c
08-11 09:37:53.670   484   484 E         : sys.mobilecare.preload = false
08-11 09:37:53.700  3709  3709 E audit   : type=1701 msg=audit(1502440673.680:286): auid=4294967295 uid=10202 gid=10202 ses=4294967295 subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 pid=11776 comm="Chrome_InProcRe" reason="memory violation" sig=4
08-11 09:37:53.850  1541 13508 E JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 104)
08-11 09:37:53.860   439   439 E lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/11740/oom_score_adj; errno=22
08-11 09:37:53.890  1541  2341 E ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ id=20, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ]
08-11 09:37:56.120 13519 13519 E TZ_CCM_SERVER: Only 'CCM' are supported
```

Comment: did you manage to find out what the `lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/10614/oom_score_adj; errno=22` message means?

Comment: I fixed this by changing how the camera app deals with the file - rather than saving in memory it would link to a file itself. Not sure if this helps you out however

Comment: thanks for the response, unfortunately my error has something to do with NDK and AudioTrack, so probably a different reason. In fact since posting that comment I have noticed that the `lowmemorykiller` message doesn't always show up after my app has been terminated, so it's probably something entirely different altogether